# Error al crear este trigger en oracle?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedure, trigger, insert

antes que nada, es mi primer pregunta. espero que mi problema y las respuestas que reciba, pueda solucionar el problema a otros.

Genero el trigger que van a ver a continuación, pero al ejecutarlo devielve el siguiente mensaje:

Warning: compiled but with compilation errors

La idea del trigger es que si el dato se cargo de un origen puntual (por eso pregunto el emisor), se inserte un registro en [TABLA DESTINO] con valores de una tabla temporal (el cual es de donde esta obteniendo el el dato).

no controlo el momento en el que se esta insertando un dato dentro de la tabla [TABLA_Y] que es quien debe disparar el trigger luego de cargar un dato.

Tengo el siguiente query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER [esquema].[nombre del trigger] AFTER insert ON [esquema].[TABLA_Y] 
REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
tmpVar NUMBER;
V_EMISOR VARCHAR2(30) := ' ';
V_FACTURA VARCHAR2(30) := ' ';
V_FECFACTURA DATE; 
BEGIN

SELECT EMISOR INTO V_EMISOR FROM [TABLATEMPORAL] WHERE ID = new.id;

SELECT FACTURA into V_FACTURA FROM [X_TABLA] WHERE A_ID = ( SELECT A_ID FROM [Z_TABLA] WHERE ID = new.id);
SELECT TO_DATE(FECFACTURA) into V_FECFACTURA FROM [TABLATEMPORAL] WHERE ID_A = ( SELECT A_ID FROM [Z_TABLA] WHERE ID = new.id);

    IF V_EMISOR = 'SARASA' THEN 
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [TABLA DESTINO] (CAMPO1, CAMPO2, CAMPO3)
        VALUES (NEW.ID, V_FACTURA, V_FECFACTURA);
        END;
    END IF;

   EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
       -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
       RAISE;
END ;
```

desde ya muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Pero, cual seria el error que tenes?

Comment: Te falto decirnos qué problema tienes.

Comment: El problema es que al querer ejecutar el query devuelve el siguiente mensaje:
Warning: compiled but with compilation errors